# Image existance checking is not working

Tags: javascript

I have used image existence checking code from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jeeah/). My code looks like:

```
var checkImage = function(src,success) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    success(src);
  };

  img.onerror = function() {
    alert('error');
  };

  img.src = src; // fires off loading of image
};
```

And I have called it as

```
var src='';
checkImage('../images/icon64x64.png',function(source){
  alert('success image'+source);
  src=source;
});
```

But every time it is giving an error even if the image exists at the given path. When I am using [this](http://www.google.com/images/logo_sm.gif) URL then neither error nor success callback called. What's being done incorrectly?

Comment: How exactly did you test that? Your fiddle works 100% for me (in Firefox).

Comment: fiddle is working , I am not saying it is not working but this code is not checking image at local path in my system.This only checks image at any given url.but doesn't fires any alert if given to success or error callback.

Comment: You said that using an image from google gets you "neither error nor success callback called", which is not true -- callbacks are being called just fine.

Comment: have u checked on jsfiddle , pls check it on local js by keeping some image file locally

Comment: Made a local html file, addressed a local image. Works just fine.

Comment: not working buddy , error callback is calling every time.I have also used this code many times but this time I don't know why error callback is calling

Comment: This can only mean that there's a problem with your path and/or the image file itself.

Comment: @Hayaßusa Now what's exactly wrong here? In your question you say "`then neither error nor success callback called`", and now in a comment above you're saying "`error callback is calling every time`" ???? Your code works in a server as well as in a local machine.

Comment: error callback everytime in the case of local file only

Comment: @Hayaßusa Maybe there's something you haven't posted, but the code you've posted works for sure. Please run this [jsFiddle snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/c7wkT/) on your local machine. It's my working test script just as I've run it. If it's not working, I amazed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
function IsValidImageUrl(url) {
    $("<img>", {
    src: url,
    error: function() { alert(url + ': ' + false); },
    load: function() { alert(url + ': ' + true); }
  });
}

IsValidImageUrl("https://www.google.com/logos/2012/hertz-2011-hp.gif");
IsValidImageUrl("http://google.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can Use jquery to check whether file exists or not

```
var checkImage=function(src){

   $.ajax({

      url:src,
      type: "HEAD",
      async: true,
      success: function()
      { 
         //This shows file is there
         // If it is there load it into your variable
      },
      error: function()
      {
       //file is not there
      },
   });
}
```

Comment: u can use error function to
 
$('#imageElement').error(function(){

    // do whatever you want  

});