# Case-sensitively checking if (video) files exist, with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I'm in the progress of writing a script, and thus far I have ran into two problems.

The first one is that I need to check if a file - or multiple files - exist with one of the hardcoded extensions I have chosen. Usually this wouldn't be too much of a problem, but in my case, the extensions are for video files (how do I check if those exist, with JS?), *and* there are relatively many extensions (10+). How can I *effectively* check if a video file exists with one of the many extensions that, as far as I can tell, have to be case-sensitive to work?

And as for the other problem; how do I calculate the dimensions of the video (or image) before it has loaded, and is put to display? Is my only option to create a kind of 'dummy' element in the DOM and load the file there, and then check the dimensions? This seems like it might cause a lag between clicking on a link and displaying the media on the page..?

EDIT: The files are on the server.
EDIT2: To clarify: I mean checking if the files exist, much like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372122/image-existance-checking-is-not-working) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609036/javascript-check-image-existence) question.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question to get answers. Can you provide some sample code? "How to check if video files exist" is hard to understand. Exists where?

Comment: Sorry, I'll add some things to my question.

Comment: Why is case sensitivity a problem, convert everything being compared toLowerCase()

Comment: I cannot access a specific file on the server if I use the wrong upper-/lowercase characters in the URL and/or file name. It'll just give me a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for files on the users computer, you can't.  It has to do with browser security, but you don't have access to a users file system, you can only access files that the user drag-drops or imports explicitly.

If the video files are on the server, then this has nothing to do with JS, but PHP or whatever your server runs from instead.

Comment: The video files are on the server. And I'm doing this in JS, so it has everything to do with JS. I know it's possible (i.e. kind of bruteforcing it, checking every extension and every upper-/lowercase combination), but that's just not doable, performance-wise.

Comment: It's only possible on your php (or whatever your server language is), from php you would generate JS code that knows about the files... but JS code directly wouldn't be able to search for the files or know anything about the files located on the server.

Comment: How come? In the second edit I made to my original question, people show examples on how to check if images exist on a server. Applying that logic, I could also check if video files existed on the server. The problem is that my conditions are a bit more limiting on what's doable performance -wise and what's not.

Comment: Images are special, and supported by browsers to search for like that.  You can do ALMOST the same with JS files by creating a script element and checking on it later... but other such things can not be done that way as they pose a security risk.  Even images are somewhat secure, as you are not able to access their binary pixel data either, just in case they are not really an image.

Comment: So you're telling me that I couldn't create a dummy `<video>` element off-screen, assign a `source` to it, and check if the video loading was succesful with a URL that I provided? If so, what would stop me?

Comment: Apparently, on IE only, you can get the `<video>` element and check for loading errors via the element.error.code value, but no other browsers support this.  Unfortunately, that still does not give you access to video dimensions or any other data of its contents.  However, your server code can know all that info and could 'tell' your JS source about it.

Comment: Well, I have a [Mozilla Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) stating that `Instead of the error event being dispatched to the media element itself, it now gets delivered to the child <source> elements corresponding to the sources resulting in the error.`, among other related things. Where did you get that no major browsers (except IE) support error checking for `<video>`?

Comment: Also, what would stop me from using AJAX calls to check for 404 codes for the files?